# D access C library on CentOS 6.5

Tags: c, codeblocks, d

I tried to write a simple D Program and use it to access a simple C library but there is unknown error.

My c Code, Box.c
    #include "Box.h"

```
int SayHello( int _int)
{
    _int ++;
    return _int;
}
```

My c header file, Box.h

```
#ifndef BOX_H_INCLUDED
#define BOX_H_INCLUDED

/* export interfaces */
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int SayHello( int _int);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // BOX_H_INCLUDED
```

I compile it

```
gcc -c Box.c Box.h
```

resulting files

```
Box.o
Box.h.gch
```

I place them to my D Program's project directory

My D Code

```
module main;

import std.stdio;
import std.conv;
import std.c.stdio;
import clib;

int main(string[] args)
{
    // test external c library
    auto s = to!string(  SayHello(3) ) ;
    writefln( "my int is "~ s );
    readln();
    return 0;
}
```

My D interface file ( clib ), trying to link to my C library

```
module clib;

import std.c.stdio;

extern (C)  int SayHello( int _int);
```

The error I get when I compile it using codeblocks

```
Compiling: hello.d
Linking console executable: bin/Debug/tutorial03-access-c-library4
obj/Debug/hello.o: In function `_Dmain':
/home/hamilton/Tutorial/tutorial03-access-c-library4/hello.d:11: **undefined reference to `SayHello'**
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings
```

Error is "undefined reference to `SayHello'"

There is no error I get when I compile it using command in console

```
$ dmd  Box.o hello.d  clib.di
```

it will be very painful if I cannot use codeblocks as I need the debugging functionality. 
Thanks

Update:

Compiler setting in codeblocks as followed
Linker for dynamic libs: gcc -m32 -lrt
Linker for static libs: ar
Debugger: gdb

Answer (score 1):

You can change the build options in CodeBlocks from `Project -> Build Options`, `Compiler settings -> Other options`. The simplest thing to do would be to just add `Box.o` to `Other options`.

Comment: Are you sure that a new build is done? Trying locally, if nothing in the source code changes, a new build will not be done.

Comment: And make sure that the compiler chosen is Digital Mars D Compiler.

Comment: yes, I have a new build but still with the same error. is it because of my compiler setting?